# Renewing SSL certificate on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, dnsimple

Our existing SSL certificate is about to expire, and so we're trying to install a new one. However, the instructions on Heroku are lacking...

### Creating the bundle

To create the bundle, you're supposed to concatenate a bunch of intermediate cert files together in the correct order. Example on Heroku:

```
$ cat EssentialSSLCA_2.crt ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > bundle.pem
```

(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-dnsimple)

We received a different set of files:

- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
- COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- (www_our_domain).crt

How should they be concatenated? Is this correct?:

```
$ cat (www_our_domain).crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > bundle.pem
```

### Adding the certs

I'm assuming we don't need to provision another SSL endpoint, we just update the one we have...

```
$ heroku certs:add server.crt server.key bundle.pem
```

(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#provision-the-add-on)

But unclear to me what happens to the old certs the add on was originally provisioned with? Are they over-written? Do they need to be removed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should they be concatenated? Is this correct?:

If you supply the 3 files `server.crt server.key bundle.pem`, you can skip `(www_our_domain).crt` in the bundle. Otherwise, simply supply a `server.crt` and a `server.key`

```
$ cat (www_our_domain).crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > server.crt
```

> I'm assuming we don't need to provision another SSL endpoint, we just update the one we have...

To update a certificate use `heroku certs:update`, not `heroku certs:add`. See the [official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#update-certificate).

Comment: Hey Simone Carletti - the `server.key` is somehow attached to the generated certificates? Actually, the task that I'm working on is updating the SSL certificate of a Rails web app and I've generated the bundle file server.crt and generated server.key on my machine but somehow I'm unable to update the certificates and getting `No key found that signs the certificate.` error. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's GUI interface is now updated to allow you to update the SSL certificate.

From Heroku -- Settings -- Copy and paste the text in your .crt file, paste in your private key and you are done.